# Como obtener valor de una respuesta POST?

Tags: java, api, spring-boot

Hola tengo un codigo en el cual realizo una llamada POST a una API, la respuesta la mapeo con @PostMapping, el problema viene cuando quier utilizar un valor de esta respuesta, no se coo hacerlo. Os dejo los codigos por aqui.

```
@Data
@Getter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class CreateHostedTokenizationSessionResponse {

 @JsonProperty("hostedTokenizationUrl")
 private String hostedTokenizationUrl;

 @JsonProperty("partialRedirectUrl")
 private String partialRedirectUrl;

 @JsonProperty("hostedTokenizationId")
 private String hostedTokenizationId;

 @JsonProperty("invalidTokens")
 private String[] invalidTokens;

 @JsonProperty("expiredCardTokens")
 private String[] expiredCardTokens;

}
```

Llamada Post.

```
@PostMapping("/hostedTokenizationSession")
public CreateHostedTokenizationSessionResponse hostedTokenizationSession() throws  IOException, InterruptedException {

    //Crear un nuevo objeto HttpClient
    HttpClient httpClient = HttpClient.newBuilder()
            .version(HttpClient.Version.HTTP_1_1)
            .build();

    HttpResponse<String> response = httpClient.send(getRequest(), HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString());
    log.info(String.format(" CREATEHOSTEDTOKENIZATION | BODY %s", response.body()));
    return OBJECT_MAPPER.readValue(response.body(), CreateHostedTokenizationSessionResponse.class);

}
```

Lo que quiero es rescatar el valor de hostedTokenizationId, para utilizarlo en otra llamada.

Comment: ¿La clase `CreateHostedTokenizationSessionResponse` no tiene un *getter* que te permita acceder a ese campo? Si no lo tiene, se lo puedes agregar y obtener el valor llamando al *getter*.

Comment: Tengo la anotacion @Data, pero al usar el getter no se porque pero no logra captar el valor. En el momento que utilizo esevalor, aparece como null

Comment: En la pregunta no se ve dónde haces eso que comentas, convendría que los mostrases pulsando en [edit].

Comment: Listo, ya esta añadido

Comment: Yo me refiero a crear en la clase `CreateHostedTokenizationSessionResponse` este método: `public String getHostedTokenizationId() { return hostedTokenizationId; }` y luego donde recibes la respuesta mapeada podrás obtener el valor haciendo algo como esto: `elObjetoDeLaRespuestaMapeada.getHostedTokenizationId()`